# GN: Delete points within a given proximity to each other. (No close neighbors.)

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using Geometry Nodes I've created some geometry where the points are too close so instances are overlapping. There are some icosphere instances on the points for demonstration.

[image]

**How can I select points within a given proximity** (in this case the selection would then be routed into the Delete Geometry node).

<sub>What I've tried so far that isn't working:</sub>

[image: The Geometry Proximity node is not working as I expected it to]

Since the geometry will update dynamically in this case, manual deletion is not an option. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use `Merge by Distance` before instantiating your objects?

Comment: @quellenform Yes! I had forgotten all about Merge by Distance. It works perfectly. Thanks! (I still am curious if there's a way to add close neighboring points to a selection too.)

Comment: I think this will (currently) not be possible without quadratic complexity, since you always have to compare each position with every other position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To merge points of a mesh or a point cloud below a certain distance, the node `Merge by Distance` is a good choice.

[image]

> *Note, however, that the mean value is used as the position for merging the points, and that the merged points can shift slightly.*